# How can I get my save back

Tags: candy-box-2

I accidentally closed the page and lost all of my progress. I was already at the castle, I'm playing this on my PC windows on chrome. I'm playing candy box 2. I've tried clicking the links and typing my save in load but nothing has worked

Answer (score 1):

Based on my personal experience, I'm pretty sure you can't.
The best thing to do is to click "Save every 10 minutes" so even if you forget to save, you can have your progress back.